# Error when passing values from dataview to datatable rowcell

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a page with two gridview; one is inside the modal pop up (grdEmpName) and the other is in the page (gvUser). Now, when the user select search button the modal pop up extender will pop up and then search employees. When the user select someone, the selected data should display to the textbox in the another gridview (gvUser).

Everything is working up to selection in modal pop up extender gridview (grdEmpName)but when I select no data pass to the other gridview. (gvUser). I need to display the selected data in the textbox.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" Width="1024px"
                PageSize="10"  
                AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  
                AllowSorting="true"  
                AllowPaging="true"  
                ShowFooter="True" 
                OnSorting="gvUser_Sorting"  
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvUser_PageIndexChanging"  
                OnRowCreated="gvUser_RowCreated"
                CssClass="Grid"  
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
                FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" > 
                <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" FirstPageImageUrl="~/images/gridview/first_16x16.png" LastPageImageUrl="~/images/gridview/last_16x16.png"  />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField> 
                        <ItemTemplate >      
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_edit_24x24.png"  title = "Edit"  _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Edit|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>'  />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_save_24x24.png" visible="false" title="Update" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Update|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex  & "|-" %>' />  
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_cancel_24x24.png" Visible="false" title="Cancel" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID")& "|Cancel|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>'  /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_delete_24x24.png" title="Delete"  _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID")& "|Delete|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|" & Eval("USR_IDNTY") %>'   /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearchUser" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_search_24x24.png" title="Search" _CommandArgument= "btnSearchUser" OnClick = "btnSearchUser_Click"  /> 
                        </ItemTemplate> 

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_add_24x24.png" title="Add" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Add|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>' /> 

                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Width="50px"  />            
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Identity" visible ="false" >

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_IDNTY" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USR_IDNTY")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_IDNTY" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("USR_IDNTY")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                 </asp:TemplateField>                        

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" SortExpression="USR_ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USR_ID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtUSR_ID" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("USR_ID")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  

                         <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUSR_ID" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>                    

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="NAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNAME" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNAME" runat="server" Width="95%" Text='<%# Bind("NAME")%>'/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNAME" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email"  SortExpression="EMAIL">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEMAIL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EMAIL")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEMAIL" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("EMAIL")%>'/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEMAIL" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"  SortExpression="ACTIVE">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkACTIVE"  runat="server" Checked ='<%# Bind("ACTIVE")%>' Enabled="false"   />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkACTIVE" runat="server" Width="95%" Checked ='<%# Bind("ACTIVE")%>'/> 
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkACTIVE" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  Wrap="False"/> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                  
                </Columns>
               <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div style="height:315px;border-style:hidden;" >
                        <table class="table" >
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding:5px;" >
                                    <img id="Img1" style="height:24px;width:24px; "  runat="server" src="images/no_data_64x64.png" />    
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px;font-size:large;">
                                     <b>No data found.</b>
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"  />
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyData" />
              </asp:GridView>
          </div>                                        

       <%-- Picker--%>

       <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>


       <cc1:ModalPopupExtender   runat="server" TargetControlID="hdControl" ID="mdlEmpListProcess"  PopupControlID="empPanel" CancelControlID="btnClose"  OnCancelScript="getFlickerSolved();" >
       </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdControl" />
      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="empPanel"  Width="909px" Height="300"  BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderColor="Gray" Style="display:none;" BackColor="Control">

       <table>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtEmpName" CssClass="textbox" Width="240"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearchEmp" CssClass="button" Text="SEARCH" OnClientClick="getFlickerSolved();"/>
                                   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClose" CssClass="button" Text="CLOSE" />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
       </table>   &nbsp;<br />
           &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div style="overflow:scroll; width:882px; height:233px;"> 
                           <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdEmpName"   Width="863px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" Height="35px" GridLines="Vertical">
                                <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="optEmp" AutoPostBack="true" _CommandArgument= "Select" OnCheckedChanged="selectedEmployee" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="USR_ID" HeaderText="USER ID"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME"  HeaderText="NAME"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="EMAIL ADDRESS">  
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>        
                                </Columns>
                               <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
                               <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                               <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                               <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                               <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                               <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                          </asp:GridView>        
         </div>
          </asp:Panel>

         <%-- End Picker--%>
```

Now, here's may code for selectedEmployee (Radio Button)

```
Protected Sub selectedEmployee(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


    Dim lnBTNDone As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(lnBTNDone.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    Dim RowIndex As Integer = gvUser.EditIndex
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = TryCast(Session("dbCache_User"), DataView).Table.Copy


    Dim dv As New DataView(dt, "", "USR_IDNTY", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
    Dim s As String = TryCast(gvUser.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblUSR_IDNTY"), Label).Text
    Dim idx As Integer = dv.Find(s)

    dv(idx)("USR_ID") = row.Cells(1).Text
    dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text
    dv(idx)("EMAIL") = row.Cells(3).Text


    gvUser.DataSource = dv
    gvUser.DataBind()

    Me.mdlEmpListProcess.Hide()

End Sub
```

But I've encounter this error when debugging **system.data.dataexception was unhandled by user code. Cannot set Name** when passing the value.

```
dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per you comment NAME is readonly field error given at runtime than you make is readonly false as below , add same line in your code after reading value

```
 dt.Columns["NAME"].ReadOnly = false
```

---

Working example

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("dataTable");
        DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn("dataColumn");
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

        // Add ten rows.
        DataRow dataRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["dataColumn"] = "item " + i;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();///add this line in your code 

        var dv = new DataView(dataTable, "", "dataColumn", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
        int index = dv.Find("item 1");
        if (index == -1)
            Console.WriteLine("Product not found");
        else
            dv[index]["dataColumn"] = "item 1000";
```

---

I suggest first check you are able to find row or not

```
          int idx = dv.Find(s);
          if (index == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Product not found");
            }
            else
            {
                dv[index]["columnname"] = "value";
            }
```

Comment: Hi.I already check and I'm able to find row and got the error still in  dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text

Comment: Yes, when debugging after passing the value on USR_ID and then pass to NAME after that I got the error. I've check "NAME" field in the table is not read-only, so I'm thinking what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Yinah - check my update and add dataTable.AcceptChanges(); in your code

Comment: @Yinah - also add this line   dt.Columns["NAME"].ReadOnly = false; before you write acceptchange() function

Comment: I already update my code then and add your suggestion but still got the same error on "NAME".

Comment: @Yinah - still readonly error ?? have you added this line dt.Columns["NAME"].ReadOnly = false if yes than do same thing with your Dv object also dv.Columns["NAME"].ReadOnly = false

Comment: No I got this error system.data.dataexception was unhandled by user code. Cannot set Name

Comment: @Yinah - hi check name field exist in you dataview , because after seeting readonly stuff error should not come

Comment: Yes, NAME field exist in my dataview